# Caliburn.Micro ListBox with ContextMenu No Target Found

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, contextmenu, caliburn.micro

I have a MasterView that have a TabControl binding with a ListView. I split the List into a secondary View becouse i want to separare the two views. The ListView have to do some operation that have nothing in common with the MasterView.

Here the code of the MasterView.xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:App"
    mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="App.MasterView"
    Title="Setup Cylinder"  
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    Height="732" Width="986"  >
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FF837F80" >
    <TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding CycleIndex}" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0,5,0,10">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Inside a MasterViewModel.cs there's a function called void public MenuItem_Open(). I want add a menu inside the ListView, that call the MenuItem_Open() of the MasterViewModel.cs.

Here is the code of the ListView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.ListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="517.5">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ScrollViewer   Margin="0,0,0,10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListBox  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedStepIndex}" x:Name="Steps" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" AlternationCount="2">
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu >
                    <MenuItem Header="New"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_New()]"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy"  />
                    <MenuItem Header="Paste" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
```

The problem is always get the error "No Target found for MenuItem_New()".

I think the problem is related to the Visual Tree Broken, and i try more solution, but everytime i failed and i get the same error.
Any hint to solve this problem?

**EDIT 1:** Binding Error

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.ListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="517.5">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ScrollViewer   Margin="0,0,0,10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListBox  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedStepIndex}" x:Name="Steps" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" AlternationCount="2">
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu >
                    <MenuItem Header="New"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_New()]"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Copy"  />
                    <MenuItem Header="Paste" />
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.MenuItem_New}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (probably), that the Data Context of MenuItems is not the MasterViewModel, but it is DataContext of ListBox.

If I am accessing properties/methods of viewModel from nested items, I just use this : `<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=DataContext.ShowSessionDetail}" CommandParameter="{Binding SessionId}">`

The LayoutRoot is name of element, which is located in root, hence its Data Context is the Data Context of ViewModel (you have also Grid with same name). Then in Path you say, you want to access Data Context of that element and then you can access methods/properties of it. This should work for you too.

Comment: I update question with Edit 1:i try add your button to check if work, but i got:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=LayoutRoot'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.MenuItem_New; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')